# ¿Cómo guardar datos obtenidos de una página web dinámica (Web scraping python) cada 10 minutos en una sola hoja de excel?

Tags: python, web, scraping

Me encuentro trabajando en un código de python para realizar web scraping de una web que cambia su contenido cada 15 min, necesito almacenar la información recolectada en una hoja de excel diaria, osea una nueva hoja cada día no cada vez que se ejecute.

El código para el web scraping ya funciona pero tengo problemas con el almacenamiento.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, antes que nada te recomiendo leer [ask] y dar el [tour]. para este caso debes colocar el código que tienes y identificar en que parte del codigo tienes problemas para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Puedes consultar este artículo, puede consultar este artículo, puede ayudarlo a resolver bien el problema: [Scraping de Datos del Sitio Web a Excel](https://www.octoparse.es/blog/scraping-de-datos-del-sitio-web-a-excel) [Simple Scraping con Google Sheets (2020 actualizado)](https://www.octoparse.es/blog/simple-scraping-con-google-sheets)